# Communication between two ViewModels using MvvmCross 5.x

Tags: c#, xamarin, mvvmcross

I'm new at Xamarin and MvvmCross and I would like to call a method in my MainViewModel from AnotherViewModel. I don't really know the best approach to do it.

I was told in the Xamarin Chat to create a Service, run it from the Setup as Singleton and save Properties in there to access it from anywhere.
Also, another user told me that there are many ways to get information between view models but I don't know any of them.

This is how I've made it work. Is this way accurate? Or should I try something else?

Thanks!

MainViewModel.cs

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Acr.UserDialogs;
using MvvmCross.Core.Navigation;
using MvvmCross.Core.ViewModels;
using App.Core.Services.Interfaces;

namespace App.Core.ViewModels
{
    public class MainViewModel : MvxViewModel, ITestService
    {
        #region Fields

        private readonly IMvxNavigationService _navigationService;
        private readonly IUserDialogs _userDialogs;
        private bool _isRunning;

        #endregion Fields

        #region Properties
        private string _description;
        public string Description
        {
            get { return _description; }
            set { _description = value; RaisePropertyChanged(() => Description); }
        }

        #endregion Properties

        #region Constructors

        public MainViewModel(IMvxNavigationService navigationService, IUserDialogs userDialogs)
        {
            _navigationService = navigationService;
            _userDialogs = userDialogs;
        }

        #endregion Constructors

        #region Public Methods

        // Implemented Methods
        public async Task<Boolean> UpdateDescription(String description)
        {
            Description = description;
            // Do more stuff
            return true;
        }

        #endregion Public Methods

        #region Private Methods

        private void SelectItem(Item item)
        {
            _navigationService.Navigate<AnotherViewModel, AnotherViewModelParameters>(new AnotherViewModelParameters()
            {
                SelectedItem = item,
                Service = this
            });
        }

        #endregion Private Methods
    }
}
```

AnotherViewModel.cs

```
using Acr.UserDialogs;
using MvvmCross.Core.Navigation;
using MvvmCross.Core.ViewModels;
using App.Core.Services.Interfaces;

namespace App.Core.ViewModels
{
    public class AnoterViewModel : MvxViewModel<AnotherViewModelParameters>
    {
        #region Fields

        private ITestService _testService;
        private readonly IMvxNavigationService _navigationService;
        private readonly IUserDialogs _userDialogs;

        #endregion Fields

        #region Properties

        // Class Properties
        private Item _item;
        public Item Item
        {
            get { return _item; }
            set { _item = value; RaisePropertyChanged(() => Item); }
        }

        // MVVM Commands
        public IMvxCommand UpdateDescriptionCommand { get; private set; }

        #endregion Properties

        #region Constructors

        public AnotherViewModel(IMvxNavigationService navigationService, IUserDialogs userDialogs)
        {
            _navigationService = navigationService;
            _userDialogs = userDialogs;

            UpdateDescriptionCommand = new MvxCommand(UpdateDescription);
        }

        #endregion Constructors

        #region Public Methods

        public override void Prepare(AnotherViewModelParameters parameter)
        {
            _item = parameter.SelectedItem;
            _testService = parameter.Service;
        }

        #endregion Public Methods

        #region Private Methods

        private async void UpdateDescription()
        {
            var response = await _testService.UpdateDescription(_item.Description);

            if(response)
            {
                await _navigationService.Close(this);
            }
        }

        #endregion Private Methods
    }
}
```

ITestService.cs

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace App.Core.Services.Interfaces
{
    public interface ITestService
    {
        Task<Boolean> UpdateDescription(String description);
    }
}
```

Comment: Possibly a better fit on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Messenger is typically better for this: https://www.mvvmcross.com/documentation/plugins/messenger